# Git does not track configuration settings in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a VC++ project, and I use Git to version my code. Everything works great, expect that if I change my configuration from Win32 to x64, Git cannot detect and thus track that change. When I clone my Repository on a new Machine, the configuration is always set to Win32 even though it is x64 for the code that was checked-in. What file(s) do I need to add to Git tracking to enable tracking of configuration?

My .gitignore file ignores the following types of files currently.

```
*.dll
*.cache
*.obj
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.log
*.scc
*.bin
*.7z
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.htm
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates
```

Comment: A quick search yielded that *.vspscc and *.vssscc are relevent, as seen here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9920911d-1a7e-4ada-90cd-b1b910586cf4/why-do-you-need-the-vspscc-and-vssscc-files?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: @RannLifshitz I have neither the *.vpscc, nor the *.vsscc files in the solutions directory (or subdirectories). So, it cannot be these, since my solution does track the configuration locally.

Comment: I'd try to brute force it then - comment out all of the ignores other then obvious size monsters (dll/so resources), commit+push everything you can, and check that your project settings exist on a repo clone on another machine. If so, check which new files were added in the last commit and update .gitignore respectively. Otherwise - the problem is not related to the project settings file (though that seems very unlikely to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **heed microsoft's warning** (below) before doing this.

Add the hidden file `.suo` that is nested in the hidden folder `.vs`

For my VS2017 TestVSSol2 solution/project, the path looked like: 
`~/source/repos/TestVSSol2/.vs/TestVSSol2/v15/.suo`

Microsoft Warning:

> The solution user options (.suo) file contains per-user solution options. This file should not be checked in to source code control.

from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

While this fixes the issue for me, clearly Microsoft discourages adding the `.suo` file any sort of version control (e.g. git). Indeed adding `.suo` is rather annoying because it requires users to delete(or git reset) their `.suo` file or the entire `.vs` directory before pulling, otherwise it seems to regularly cause merge conflicts on the .suo file.

Nevertheless, it has been the only way I can figure out how to cause persistence changes in the configuration properties. Otherwise actions such as setting a project in a solution to a static library just isn't captured in the repository.

---

edit: Instead of directly adding the `.suo` file to the source control, I recommend creating a copy of the `.suo` file in another folder and adding the copy to the repository. Users of the repository will need to manually overwrite their `.suo` with the copy you made when they clone/fork, but it will prevent git from constantly detecting changes to the .suo file every time you open visual studio.